# [iOS][MagicalRecord][CoreData] Data handling

Tags: ios, core-data, dictionary, magicalrecord

I got a problem with an iOS map application.
I think it comes from a concurrent access to the same data at the same time.
But the error is not realy explicit.

What does the application:

- add location record when the user updates his location. (**LocationManager**)
- display location on map (**MapViewController**)

If I do not add any location, I do not get any error.
If I add one and at the same time displaying a map (which use the location record from MagicalRecord) I got this error or a bad access:

> error:  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan -2.60432e+07]'

Here is a screen recording of the bug: [Screen recording](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCGr03ikSFA&feature=youtu.be)

I made test with performing all the data manipulation on the main thread, I still can't figure out the error

If someone could help me, he will save my day.

Thanks.

Comment: im sorry I don't follow. please exxplain again what you WANT and what you HAVE

Comment: Error saying that you are trying to set frame or position or something with NAN(Not a number).

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that the immediate cause of the problem is concurrency mishandling, since all of your ui related methods should be called on the main thread, although it could be the root cause. Now, as the error says, what happens is that a `CALayer` position coordinate is set to `NaN` at some point. This usually happens because of a division by zero. To find out where it happens, enable the exception breakpoints. When you see which layer is throwing the exception, see if its `x` or `y` is `NaN`, and if it is, see where you set it to be `NaN`

Comment: I checked all the values used to display stuffs on map, used breakpoint too.

Answer (score 0):

LocationManager:

```
- (void)setupLocationRecord:(CLLocation *)location {
LocationRecord *locationRecord = [LocationRecord createEntity];

locationRecord.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude];
locationRecord.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.longitude];
locationRecord.createdAt = [NSDate date];
locationRecord.updatedAt = [NSDate date];

[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveNestedContexts];

//[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(addLocation:) withObject:locationRecord];
[locationRecord debug];
[self addLocation:locationRecord];
```

}

MapViewController:

```
- (void)setupMap {
NSArray *array = [LocationRecord findAllSortedBy:@"idLocation" ascending:YES];
NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, array);
self.mapView.locationsRecordList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
```

}

Comment: This should be an edit to your question, not an answer. (This isn't a forum.)